# Copying Large Excel Files into 500 row Smaller Files

Tags: excel, vba

I have the vba code below in Excel that *almost* works. I'm having an issue where the "firstrow" isn't increasing. The first file will contain rows 1-501, the second file will contain 1-1001 (I want it to contain row 1 & 502-1001). I'm sure it's a small issue but I've stared at it for a while and can't seem to figure out whats wrong. Some help would be really awesome!!

```
Sub FiveHundredLineCopy()

Dim Firstrow As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim Copyrange As String
Dim Startcell As String
Dim Month, Year As String

Firstrow = 2    'Starts on row 2 to exclude header
Lastrow = Firstrow + 499
Month = Nov 'Month of Clinic for filename
Year = 2014 'Year of Clinic for filename
Filenumber = 1  'First file in sequence

Let Startcell = "A" & Firstrow
Let Copyrange = "A" & Firstrow & ":" & "BZ" & Lastrow       'Only copying through column BZ

Do While Range(Startcell) <> ""
    Range("A1:BZ1", Copyrange).Copy    'Includes A1:BZ1 to copy header row as well
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
    NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("AJ2").Text & "_Sams_Apex_" & Month & " " & Year & "_File " & Filenumber & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    NewBook.Close Savechanges:=False

    Firstrow = Firstrow + 500
    Lastrow = Firstrow + 499
    Filenumber = Filenumber + 1
    Let Startcell = "A" & Firstrow
    Let Copyrange = "A" & Firstrow & ":" & "BZ" & Lastrow
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Range(Cell1, Cell2) selects the cells starting from Cell1 through Cell2.  You can copy and paste the header first and then the Copyrange you want after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending the `Copyrange` from the header row to the last row that you want to copy. As mentioned, you could run two operations or hide the rows that have already been copied.

```
Do While Range(Startcell) <> ""
    Range("A1:BZ1", Copyrange).Copy    'Includes A1:BZ1 to copy header row as well
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
    NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("AJ2").Text & "_Sams_Apex_" & Month & " " & Year & "_File " & Filenumber & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    NewBook.Close Savechanges:=False

    'hide the ones already copied. hidden rows will not be copied to the new location
    copyrange.resize(copyrange.rows.count - 1, copyrange.columns.count).offset(1, 0).entirerow.hidden = true

    Firstrow = Firstrow + 500
    Lastrow = Firstrow + 499
    Filenumber = Filenumber + 1
    Let Startcell = "A" & Firstrow
    Let Copyrange = "A" & Firstrow & ":" & "BZ" & Lastrow
Loop
```

Don't forget to unhide all of the rows after the splitting operation has completed.

Comment: Ohhhh! That makes sense! Thank you!